# Is the phase of a digital filter always an odd function from $[-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: filters, phase, finite-impulse-response

Trying to prove something about the integral of the phase of an FIR from, does this hold true at all? Or maybe for some?

Comment: yes, if the impluse response is real, then the phase is an odd-symmetry function.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on RBJ's comment from above, your statement is true iff the impulse response of the filter is real. Recall that the frequency response of a filter is the [discrete time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) of its impulse response. That is:

$$
X(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{j\omega n}
$$

Look at the relationship between $X(\omega)$ and $X(-\omega)$:

$$
X(-\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{-j\omega n}
$$
$$
X(-\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \left(e^{j\omega n}\right)^*
$$

If $x[n]$ is real, then we can absorb it into the conjugate:

$$
X(-\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(x[n] e^{j\omega n}\right)^*
$$

And since conjugation is a linear operation, we can pull it around the sum as well:

$$
X(-\omega) = \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{j\omega n}\right)^*
$$
$$
X(-\omega) = \left(X(\omega)\right)^*
$$

So $X(\omega)$ exhibits [Hermitian symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function); its phase is oddly symmetric about $\omega = 0$, while its magnitude is evenly symmetric.

Comment: the only thing i would do is change $X(\omega)$ to $X(e^{j \omega})$ and keep the DTFT pretty much compatible with the ZT.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this is not "so true", unless you are more precise about how you define the phase, not uniquely defined in general, up to $2\pi$. However, if you consider the  principal value of the phase in $(-\pi,\pi]$ interval, or a periodization of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a torus (identifying $-\pi$ to $\pi$), then you can derive the result in an intuitive way, using known properties for real signals:

- the real part $\mathcal{R} $ of the Fourier transform $X$ of $x$ is even,
- the imaginary part $\mathcal{I} $  of its Fourier transform is odd.

Hence $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{R} $ is odd, and since the $\arctan$ function is odd, then :

$$ \operatorname{Arg}(X) = \operatorname{atan2}\Big(\mathcal{I}(X),\, \mathcal{R}(X)\Big) =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{\mathcal{I}(X)}{\mathcal{R}(X)}\right) &\text{if } \mathcal{R}(X) > 0, \\
\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{\mathcal{R}(X)}{\mathcal{I}(X)}\right) &\text{if } \mathcal{I}(X) > 0, \\
-\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{\mathcal{R}(X)}{\mathcal{I}(X)}\right) &\text{if } \mathcal{I}(X) < 0, \\
\arctan\left(\frac{\mathcal{I}(X)}{\mathcal{R}(X)}\right) + \pi &\text{if } \mathcal{R}(X) < 0, \ \mathcal{I}(X) \ge 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{\mathcal{I}(X)}{\mathcal{R}(X)}\right) - \pi &\text{if } \mathcal{R}(X) < 0, \ \mathcal{I}(X) < 0 \\
\text{undefined} &\text{if } \mathcal{R}(X) = 0, \ \mathcal{I}(X) = 0
\end{cases} $$

is odd.

Comment: if you're gonna be precise about phase, Laurent, you need to fix your $\operatorname{Arg}(X)$ equation.  i might do it, but i hesitate to modify your answer without consent.

Comment: I trust your input on that one